# Set top position to draggable child inside draggable parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a nested draggable elements. **[My Fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/02whq4ky/2/)**

What I want is to set the top limit of the draggable child element so that the child element never overlaps the parent heading.

I contained it within the parent but not be able to set the top position so that it won't drag to the parent heading.

```
 _________________________
|_Parent__________________|   <------- Don't overlap the containing parent heading
|                         |
|     ___________         |
|    |_Child_____|        |        
|    |           |        |
|    |           |        |
|    |           |        |
|    |___________|        |
|_________________________|
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="Parent">
         <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Parent</h4>

        <div id="Child">
             <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Child</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background: Yellow;
}
#Parent {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: grey;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
#Child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

**Script:**

```
 $(function () {
     $('#Parent').draggable({
         cursor: 'move',
         containment: 'parent'
     });

     $("#Child").draggable({
         cursor: 'move',
         containment: 'parent'
     });
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding an extra container after the `parent`'s heading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the limit while you are dragging by using the following code. Just try to reset the `top position` of your draggable child by calling the method when on [event drag](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) in `$("#Child").draggable({})`. For you current scenario `top: -20` is suitable but if you have a bigger header in your parent draggable, then set the value accordingly.

```
drag: function (event, ui) {
     var divPos = ui.position.top;
     if (divPos < -20) {

         ui.position.top = -20;

     }
}
```

[Here is working **JSFiddle**.](http://jsfiddle.net/02whq4ky/4/)

---

Given below is embedded snippet of your code.

```js
 $(function() {
   $('#Parent').draggable({
     cursor: 'move',
     containment: 'parent'
   });

   $("#Child").draggable({
     cursor: 'move',
     containment: 'parent',
     drag: function(event, ui) {

       var divPos = ui.position.top;
       if (divPos < -20) {

         ui.position.top = -20;

       }
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background: Yellow;
}
#Parent {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: grey;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#Child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="Parent">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Parent</h4>

    <div id="Child">
      <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Child</h4>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Containment wrapper to contain the movement.
source: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

For your specific problem:

Add this to the CSS

```
 #containment-wrapper { width: 100%; height:90%; position:relative; top:-20px;}
```

Change your HTML like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="Parent">
        <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Parent</h4>
        <div id="containment-wrapper">
          <div id="Child">
             <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Child</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js changes:

```
$(function () {
     $('#Parent').draggable({
         cursor: 'move',
         containment: 'parent'
     });

     $("#Child").draggable({
         cursor: 'move',
         containment: '#containment-wrapper',
         scroll: false 
     });
 });
```

Hope it helps